# Can only assign "" as value to input type file

Tags: javascript, html, file, input

I've the following code that checks if I file is .jpg,.jpeg or .png:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onchange="this.size = Math.max(this.value.length, 7)+15;read(this)" id="myinput" style="min-width: 50px;" 
      />

</body>
</html>

<script>

var myfile=""
async function read(input) {
  var file = input.files[0];
  var idxDot = file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
  var extFile = file.name.substr(idxDot, file.name.length).toLowerCase();
  if (extFile=="jpg" || extFile=="jpeg" || extFile=="png"){
      //fileContent = await readFile(file);
      myfile=file
      alert("Valid file selected!");
  }else{
      alert("Only jpg, jpeg or png allowed");
      input.value = myfile;
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm attempting that if a file different to that ones is selected the last value of a taken valid file displays.

But that only happens, at the beginning, after a valid file has been taken. if I choose another one the path shown in the input changes to that of the selected file even if it's not a valid one.

Is there any way to solve this issue so the path that displays is always the one of the last valid file?

Comment: You can't set the value of a `file` input in JavaScript, it can only be set by the user using the file picker.

Comment: @Barmar. but assigning "" works. Why that one and not others?

Comment: Because it just clears it, so that's allowed. You can't assign a specific file, that would be a security problem.

Comment: @Barmar, I see, it makes sense. Guess I'll check on button that posts the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little bit of a hack but may give you what you need

```js
var myfile={name:"none"};
 function read(input) {
  var file = input.files[0];
  var idxDot = file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
  var extFile = file.name.substr(idxDot, file.name.length).toLowerCase();
  var span =document.getElementById('last');
  if (extFile=="jpg" || extFile=="jpeg" || extFile=="png"){
      //fileContent = await readFile(file);
      myfile=file      
      alert("Valid file selected!");
       span.style.display='none';
  }else{
      alert("Only jpg, jpeg or png allowed");
      input.value = '';     
      span.style.display='inline';
      span.innerHTML = "Last valid File was: " + myfile.name
  }
}
```

```css
span{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" align="center" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onchange="this.size = Math.max(this.value.length, 7)+15;read(this)" id="myinput" style="min-width: 50px;" 
      />
      <span id='last'></span>

</body>
</html>
```